# Why does asterisk wildcard fail with sub() command? [r]

Tags: r, replace

When using the sub() function in R, how do we use an asterisk wildcard to replace all characters after (or before) an indicator?

If we want to remove an underscore and all arbitrary text afterward:

```
x <- c("a_101", "a_275", "b_133", "b_277")
```

The following code removes nothing:

```
sub(pattern = "_*", replacement = "", x = x)
[1] "a_101" "a_275" "b_133" "b_277"
```

Desired output:

```
"a" "a" "b" "b"
```

Why does the wildcard fail?

Comment: `*` is not a wildcard in the sense that you mean. `_*` simply means any number of `_` characters (including none).  You might be wanting `_.*`, where the `.` is a wildcard.

Comment: I think @AndrewGustar has the solution. I'd like to put in a plug for https://regex101.com/ which lets you test out your regular expressions and see exactly what they're doing and why

Comment: The reason your code does not even remove one `_` is because `sub` looks for the first match of `_*`, which turns out to be zero `_`s at the start of the string.  `sub` only does the first substitution, whereas `gsub` does all that it can find, and would delete the `_` characters.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you! Your comment/answer is what I was looking for. One question: could you clarify what it means that "`sub` only does the first substitution"? To my untrained eye, it does zero substitutions. As I understand "the first substitution" I would expect this output: "a101" "a_275" "b_133" "b_277"

Comment: `sub` does one substitution of a zero-length sequence of `_` characters for an empty string. It does this for each element of your vector.  Which of course boils down to nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using sub, you have to specify everything you want to replace, and what you want to replace it with.  Here I've done that using a group function for the letter of interest.

```
sub('([a-z])_\\d+', replacement = '\\1', x)
[1] "a" "a" "b" "b"
```

Using the wild card will work too.

```
sub('([a-z])_.*', replacement = '\\1', x)
[1] "a" "a" "b" "b"
```

And finally more along the lines of what you were thinking:

```
sub('_.*', replacement = "", x)
[1] "a" "a" "b" "b"
```